# Self Referential Polynomials

Tags: code-golf, math, number, linear-algebra, polynomials

For every given degree \$n\$ it is possible to construct (at least one) an integral polynomial \$p \in \mathbb Z[X]\$ such that \$p(k)\$ (\$p\$ evaluated in \$k\$) is the coefficient of the term \$x^k\$ in the polynomial for all \$0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\$. To make them unique, we require the leading coefficient (the coefficient of \$x^n\$) to be positive and minimal.

These polynomials have some interesting properties, you can find some references in the [thread that inspired me to do this challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4lnlfy/selfreferential_polynomials/). You can also find those polynomials in https://oeis.org/A103423

One of the a priori unexpected properties is how the roots behave depending on \$n\$:

[image]

[source (by /u/zorngov and /u/EpicSauceSc2)](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4lnlfy/selfreferential_polynomials/d3ozkom)

#### Task

Given a nonnegative integer \$n\$ output the self referential integral polynomial of degree \$n\$ with minimal positive leading coefficient.

#### Details

The output can be in any human readable form, as string `x^2-x-1`, or also as a list of coefficients `[1,-1,-1]`. (The order of the coefficients can also be the other way around, it just needs to be consistent.)

#### First few outputs

```
n=0: 1
n=1: x
n=2: x^2-x-1
n=3: 10*x^3-29*x^2-6*x+19
n=4: 57*x^4-325*x^3+287*x^2+423*x-19
n=5: 12813*x^5-120862*x^4+291323*x^3+44088*x^2-355855*x-227362
```

Comment: Congrats on your gold badge!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, apparently I'm a fanatic.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

```
NullSpace@Table[x^c-Boole[r==c]/.x->r,{r,0,#},{c,0,#}]&
```

Output is the list coefficients, beginning from the constant term. Example:

```
In[1084] := Do[Print[%1077[n] // StandardForm], {n, 0, 7}]

{{1}}

{{0,1}}

{{-1,-1,1}}

{{19,-6,-29,10}}

{{-19,423,287,-325,57}}

{{-227362,-355855,44088,291323,-120862,12813}}

{{145991969,64989065,-123338281,-85635661,79841909,-18146731,1286795}}

{{-5958511844199,3384370785404,8437850634901,489428412300,-4499161007143,1776194531596,-258931801371,13131073916}}
```

---

This simply finds the vector such that `(A - I)v = 0`, similar to the MAPLE code in OEIS. The `NullSpace` method seems to always pick the minimal positive number for the last element, which matches the task description.

The `x^c-…/.x->r` indirection is to prevent having `0^0 == Indeterminate`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), 74 bytes

```py
lambda n:kernel(matrix(n+1,[j^-i-(-i==j)for i in[-n..0]for j in[0..n]])).0
```

The `-i` and `[-n..0]` could be `i` and `[0..n]`, if not for the positive leading coefficient requirement.

[Try it on Sage Cell](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVTIs8pOLcpLzdHITSwpyqzQyNM21InOitPN1NXQzbS1zdJMyy9SyFTIzIvWzdPTM4gFcbNAXAM9vbzYWE1NPQNeLrgaoKBprFVBUWZeiUKaRqYmAMYlIAU=&lang=sage)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 57 bytes

```
n->(a=matkerint(matrix(n++,,i,j,i--^j--)-1))*sign(a[n,1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxCoAwDAC/EpwSTcA@oH5EFDrYEsVYqoO/r8Xhjlsuh6KSco3gq8mEwZ/hObai9mCroi/aMDAr76wi6y5C4oj6W5NhmI3dQjVeBQ08jAyukf/doAOZmiIaEdUP)

Returns the coefficients as a column vector.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 172 bytes

Similar to the Mathematica code in OEIS.

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5BCsIwELznFUtPCbbYXKM5eBQ851IrxJqUrekqqYH@vibisLCzO8MwUwpo5bptaUEa4YLkbDyF0d2jZT7R8MEXgeckGGnaSWY0pRCWtx0c79C7sDj@BK1B1mX4BA1Iccu/sgX4V4QJkEAqquH5Z31Wz6JTtewZem46R4/@2AowujGHfDBu9rNdcU4zN0IUXTVSZXtmWwmlEtUq2TLIeEekDy89a6iuVImf7ws)

```
using LinearAlgebra
function f(n)
n=n+1
V=nullspace([ifelse(k == 1, 1, (j - 1)^(k - 1)) for j in 1:n, k in 1:n] - I)[:,1]
if(V[end]<0) V=-V;end
(V/maximum(V))[end:-1:1]
end
```

---

Here, these coefficients are normalized by dividing by the maximum value of the coefficients.

**How to adjust the code?**

```
using LinearAlgebra

function VM(n)
    return [ifelse(k == 1, 1, (j - 1)^(k - 1)) for j in 1:n, k in 1:n]
end

function f(n)
    V = nullspace(VM(n + 1) - I)
    V = V[:, 1] # Get the first column
    if V[end] < 0
        V = -V
    end
    return (V / maximum(V))[end:-1:1] # Normalize and reverse
end

for n in 0:10
    print(f(n), "\n")
end
```